# Overriding functions from base class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm having a bit of trouble overriding a function from a base class.

Here's my GameObject class:

```
namespace GameEngine {
    class GameObject {
    public:
        virtual void render() {
            std::cout << "Render Game Object" << std::endl;
        }
    };
}
```

And here's my Player class:

```
class Player : public GameEngine::GameObject {
public:
    void render() {
        std::cout << "Render Player" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In MainComponent.cpp I have a Vector of GameObjects, and I loop through them to render them

```
Player player;
vector<GameEngine::GameObject> gameObjects;

void MainComponent::init() {
    gameObjects.push_back(player);

    gameLoop();
}

void MainComponent::render() {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        gameObjects[i].render();
    }
}
```

I would expect this code to output "Render Player", since the only object in the gameObjects vector is a Player, but instead it outputs "Render Game Object". Is there a way that I can force the Player object in the gameObjects vector to use the Player render as opposed to the GameObject render?

Comment: This has nothing to do with overloading. `Player::render` **overrides** `GameObject::render`.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right, my mistake, I edited the post to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base
>   class, a call to a overridden virtual function would invoke the
>   behavior defined in the derived class.

You must store pointer to the base class instead base object value into the vector.

```
Player player;
vector<GameEngine::GameObject*> gameObjects;

void MainComponent::init() {
    gameObjects.push_back(&player);

    gameLoop();
}

void MainComponent::render() {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        gameObjects[i]->render();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your vector contains `GameObject`s by value. Therefore pushing a subclass instance into this vector does object slicing: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

You should be using `GameObject` pointers, or preferably `shared_ptr<GameObject>`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler version of the code that illustrates the same problem:

```
GameEngine::GameObject object = player;
object.render();
```

The problem is that the `player` object gets converted to a `GameObject` by slicing off the base part of the `player`. So what gets stored is a `GameObject`, not a `Player` object.

The solution is to use a pointer or a reference instead of an object:

```
GameEngine::GameObject *ptr = &player;
ptr->render();
```

You need to do the same thing in `gameObjects`: instead of storing objects of type `GameObject` it should store pointers to `GameObject`:

```
std::vector<GameEngine::GameObject*> gameObjectPointers;
gameObjectPointers.push_back(&player);
gameObjectPointers[0]->render();
```

Once you do this you have to pay close attention to object lifetimes. If `player` gets destroyed before `gameObjectPointers` does, then `gameObjectPointers[0]` points to an object that doesn't exist any more, and using it will make bad things happen.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way that I can force the Player object in the gameObjects vector to use the Player render as opposed to the GameObject render?

No. You're declaring the `vector` with type `vector<GameEngine::GameObject> gameObjects;`, so the base class' instances will be stored in the `vector`. And when `gameObjects.push_back(player);`, the object will be [slicing copied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/3309790), there's no `Player`.

You can store pointer of the base class into the `vector`, and better to use smart pointer to avoid manual memory mangement. For example:

```
vector<unique_ptr<GameEngine::GameObject>> gameObjects;

void MainComponent::init() {
    gameObjects.emplace_back(new Player);
    // or gameObjects.push_back(unique_ptr(new Player));
    gameLoop();
}

void MainComponent::render() {
    for(int i = 0; i < gameObjects.size(); i++) {
        gameObjects[i]->render();
    }
}
```